# How to extract text using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file and want to extract only the text beginning and ending with a certain strings using `sed`.

For example, in the line:

```
string>![TEST[Extract this string]>/string>
```

I want to get

```
Extract this string
```

How would you implement this with `sed`? Basically I want to get text that start with the expression "`string>![TEST[`" and end with the expression "`]>/string>`".

Comment: It's ppossible with sed,awk , perl and so on, It's related to your job!

Comment: this look like XML CDATA part. are you sure you dont want to use xml/xsl tools ?

Comment: You really need sed?

Comment: Why not use grep (or egrep) for this type of situation?

Answer (score 8):

```
sed -e 's/string>!\[TEST\[\(.*\)]>\/string>/\1/' file
```

or

```
sed -e 's|string>!\[TEST\[\(.*\)]>/string>|\1|' file
```

Output:

```
Extract this string
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell the string not only what to match, but what to save as well:

```
sed -ne 's@string>!\[TEST\[\([^]]*\)\]>/string>@\1@gp'
```

The `s` command in `sed` takes two arguments: a regular expression and a replacement string.  Typically, the `/` delimiter is used to separate the two, but you can use any character, in this case `@`.  There are some special characters in the regular expressions, like `[`, `]`.  These would need to be quoted with `\` if you want the real character, e.g. `string>!\[`.  The `\([^]]*\)` captures everything between the square brackets. And the `\1` replaces the string with what matched the regular expression. At the end is `@gp`, which tells that sending to match multiple times on the line (`g`) and print the replaced line (after we tell `sed` to not print lines with the `-n` option.

Comment: To make a pattern shorter `sed -ne 's@\(string>\)!\[TEST\[\([^]]*\)\]>/\1@\2@gp'`

Comment: It captures everything which is not a right-side square bracket.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach with Awk:

```
awk -F'[][]' '{print $3}' file
```

Comment: Correct if there is the one string occurance in line.

Comment: @Costas Like I said, a simple approach (and based on the total amount of information provided by the OP)...

Comment: So to be fully correct to OP it shoul be `awk -F'string>\\!\\[TEST\\[|\\]' '$0 ~ FS{print $2}'`

Comment: @Costas Sure, but that no longer qualifies as "simple". :)

Comment: Simple? See [mikeserv answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188789/89144)

Comment: @Costas Well, pretty much anything is simple by that comparison...

Comment: @mikeserv I agree that the question could be read that way; but equally, given the lack of specificity, it could be read exactly the way I interpreted it. You approach is undoubtedly more comprehensive, but there is nothing wrong with taking the question on face value either, IMO.

Comment: @mikeserv There was no need to defend your own: your familiarity with `sed` is truly impressive and my comment was a mixture of jest and admiration...

Comment: @jasonwryan What's `-F'[][]'`? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: @jasonwryan Why `awk -F'[[]]' ` does not work?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/\n/P;//D;y|]|\n|
    s|\n>/string>|]|
    y|[]\n|\n[]|
    s|string>!\nTEST\n\(.*\[\)|[\1|
    y|\n[|[\n|;D' <<\IN
    string>![TEST[][]Extract[ ]this[ ]string[][]>/string>
IN
```

It maybe that you can specify that the square brackets are acceptable delimiters here, but, if so, it seems strange that the end delimiters would be so elaborate in that case. And anyway, as the question only states that you need to get *text* from between `string>![TEST[` and `]>/string>` and so that's what this tries to do - though it does fail if *text* should span newline boundaries.I

Anyway, it works by:

1. `y|]|\n|` - It first translates all occurrences of `]` on a line for a `\n`ewline.
2. `s|\n>/string>|]|` - It next replaces the first occurring `\n`ewline which is followed immediately by your right end delimiter with `]` *(which makes it the only possible `]` on a line at that time)*.
3. `y|[]\n|\n[]|` - If the last substitution was successful that one `]` is translated to a `[` while all `\n`ewlines are translated back to `]` and all `[` are simultaneously translated to `\n`ewlines - the three character types are shifted, basically.
4. `s|string>!\nTEST\n\(.*\[\)|[\1|` - If the left end delimiter is found preceding a `[` at that time then it must be that both ends of the first occurrence of *text* have been found. That match is substituted for `[`.
5. `y|\n[|[\n|` - And so in the last translation if there are any `[` on a line at all they will become newlines and all newlines will become `[`.

At this point everything up to the first occurring newline *(or the entire line if there are none at all)* is `D`eleted. If anything remains it is sent to the top of the script. If the previous iteration resulted in two `\n`ewlines in pattern space - both ends of your delimited *text* then it is `P`rinted up to the first occurring `\n`ewline. Else the pattern space already tested is cleared and the cycle continues.

And so the above example prints:

```
][]Extract[ ]this[ ]string[][
```

...and it will print each on a separate line as many similarly delimited strings as can be fully left and right delimited per line or nothing at all.

Comment: In the case cn be more simple `sed -e 's#[^!]*string>!\[TEST\[\|\]>/string>[^!]*##g'`?

Comment: @Costas - no. That doesn't work if there is more than one per line - or if the left-end delimiter occurs within *text*.

Comment: Agree. What you say re`'s#string>!\[TEST\[\|\]>/string>$#^#g;s/[^^]*^\([^^]*\)^[^^]*/\1 /g'` If you do not sure in `^` free to change it by some more exotic.

Comment: @Costas - exotic doesn't work for unknown strings - it doesn't matter how *rare* it is - if it is a possibility then it is a bug. You have to sanitize it first, or use delimiters that cannot otherwise occur.

Answer (score 1):

Through GNU `grep`,

```
$ echo 'string>![TEST[Extract this string]>/string> foo bar string>![TEST[Extract this string]>/string>' | grep -oP 'string>!\[TEST\[\K.*?(?=]>/string>)'
Extract this string
Extract this string
```

Answer (score 0):

Also answered & tested here including extract Key Value from JSON example using only `grep` :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694241/518235

No `jq`, `awk`, `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
json='{"access_token":"kjdshfsd", "key2":"value"}' 
    
echo $json | grep -o '"access_token":"[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

Tested & working here: https://ideone.com/Fw4How

source: https://brianchildress.co/parse-json-using-grep

Comment: I'm not sure if this might have served better as a "Related:" comment under the question, unless you [edit] and include the details from your previous answer in this answer.