# How to find value of key-value in json in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, json

I'm trying to write a bash script with make s curl call and get a json document back. The json document has a key called `access_token` and I need to extract the value of this field. This is my json document

```
echo $json

{"access_token":"kjdshfsd", "key2":"value"}
```

I don't have `jq` installed.

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551159/parse-value-from-different-json-strings-no-jq

Comment: Also note that if this response is received via curl it's almost certain the json object will not be in the same order upon subsequent requests.  (ie. A proper json parser is the only real solution)

Answer (score 20):

The short answer: Install `jq`

You shouldn't parse json without a json parser.

To do this with `jq`:

```
echo "$json" | jq -r '.access_token'
```

or, without letting `echo` expand encoded tabs and newlines,

```
jq -r -n --argjson data "$json" '$data.access_token'
```

---

My preferred json parser is [json](https://github.com/trentm/json), using it you could do:

```
echo "$json" | json access_token
```

**Note:** both of these solutions assume your json object is exactly (or at least pretty much exactly) as you have shown in your example.

Comment: for some reasons I can't install jq

Comment: Also note I have provided a non-jq solution as well.

Comment: @HHH Also note that `jq` [is available for download](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in a form that does not require root access for installation. There is really _no reason_ to write a bad JSON parser yourself when you're much better off downloading `jq` into your home directory and using it from there.

Answer (score 19):

No `jq`, `awk`, `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
json='{"access_token":"kjdshfsd", "key2":"value"}' 
    
echo $json | grep -o '"access_token":"[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

Tested & working here:  https://ideone.com/Fw4How

source: https://brianchildress.co/parse-json-using-grep

Comment: If anyone reading this in future and the last grep doesn't work, you can try removing the "$" and instead appending | tail -1
`grep -o '[^"]*' | tail -1`

Comment: You could use the `-E`/`--extended-regexp` argument of _grep_ (to select the wanted key-value) and then pipe _sed_ (to remove the key). Something like: `echo $json | grep -oE '"access_token":"[^"]+' | sed -e 's/"access_token":"\(.*\)/\1/'`

Comment: Or, even better, use the `-P`/`--perl-regexp` argument of _grep_ with look-behind and look-ahead. Something like: `echo $json | grep -oP '(?<="access_token":")[^"]+(?=")'`

Comment: @PaoloRovelli: (1) Piping one ``grep`` into another `grep` is somewhat unaesthetic, but it’s sometimes a good approach.  Piping `grep` into `sed` is almost always overkill; `sed` is powerful enough that you almost never need to combine it with `grep`.  See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729048/80216) for how to do this using `sed` and not `grep`. (2) If you have a new, different answer, I suggest that you post it as an answer.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' If you see [my second comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551193/how-to-find-value-of-key-value-in-json-in-bash-script/694241?noredirect=1#comment1382112_694241) it can be done with a single grep (tested here: https://ideone.com/Z6sOBp). That said, I also like your sed-based solution. :)

Comment: This was so minimal and straight forward, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can't install a json parser then assuming your strings cannot contain double quotes or newlines, every record is on a single line and that every tag and value are double-quote-enclosed strings as in your posted sample input, this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/"[^"]*"/) ) {
        hit = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        if ( ++cnt % 2 ) {
            tag = hit
        }
        else {
            val = hit
            f[tag] = val
        }
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print f[tgt]
}

$ echo "$json" | awk -v tgt='access_token' -f tst.awk
kjdshfsd

$ echo "$json" | awk -v tgt='key2' -f tst.awk
value
```

Answer (score 1):

`pcregrep` has a smarter `-o` option
that allows you to request an individual capture group. 
So,

```
echo "$json" | pcregrep -o1 '"access_token":"([^"]*)'
```

This is basically the same as [social’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694241/80216),
except it doesn’t require as many processes.

---

Or, doing the (conceptually) same thing entirely in `sed`,

```
echo "$json" | sed -En 's/.*"access_token":"([^"]*).*/\1/p'
```

This is inspired by [Paolo Rovelli’s comment](/questions/551193/how-to-find-value#comment1382111_694241).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option to `jq`, recents version of miller (`mlr`) support JSON input as long as it represents tabular data like in your case of  a JSON object with only scalar values which is like a row in a table.

```
printf %s "$json" | mlr --j2n cut -f access_token
```

`mlr` has that advantage (or disadvantage depending on PoV) of not reformatting values. For instance `1e1` or `10.00000000000000001` would not become `10`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option for extracting a value.

```
#! /bin/sh

fileName=$1
keyName=$2

# replace all of the comments from the file with newlines.
sed -i 's|,|\n|g' $fileName

# Grab all of the text after the colon (:) on the line containing the key and save it off as a variable named value
value=$(grep $keyName $fileName | cut -d ":" -f2-)

echo $value
```

Please note, this process is destructive (it uses sed's in-place editing). If you care about the json file you're reading from you should make a copy of it first. Also, it does not trim off the quotation marks around the value. If you wish to remove them also, I suggest using substring.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the "access_token", and you kow the format is not too difficult (no quote escapes etc.) then this will do it...

```
grep -oP '"access_token":"\K[^"]+'  <<< "$json"
```

- The `<<< "$json` feeds the string into "grep"
- The -oP options mean only the 'matching part' of the perl regex is to be returned.
- The '\K' in the perl-RE means find the part before, but only match (return) the part after.

The result is that it finds the key, and returns the value (up until the first quote).

Fast small simple!   Works for many key-value file formats, not just json!